# My app cant pass the Google Play review because Google says REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES is present, but it is not

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I am using open_filex package especially to avoid this problem. I am confused because the permission is nowhere to be found in my particular Android manifests and manifest merge file.

I have tried to manually remove permission by tool:remove
tried open_file_safe library as well. Just stopped passing reviews for some reason, maybe something is connected to newer Android version (13).

Comment: Please share your merged manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to your AndroidManifest in order to explicity remove the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"/>
```

and on your manifest tag add

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

so that it looks something like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="*" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

Then build your apk or aab and then upload it Google Play Store and then **submit the build for release to ALL the tracks; Internal testing, Closed testing(Alpha & Track), Open testing and Production regardless of whether the track is active or not.** This is a very important step. Your build will not be rejected.

Comment: is releasing build onto all tracks the problem? I was seding it to open beta only sine some time ago. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: I am not 100% sure about this but I think the issue is if you have a track with a previous build that still requests for that permission then they will reject it for some reason even on an inactive track. When I had that issue a few weeks ago, I read on a github issue that I needed to deploy to all the tracks and once I did, they accepted the build.